# Using a Custom rotation in "Instantiate" - Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I'am trying to make a throwing spear mechanic in my game.
The problem is that when i instantiate/spawn my "spear" its not facing the right direction i want it to be facing, forward in a 90 degree angle in the X and Y rotation. I tried to give it a rotation like this:

**Instantiate(Spear.GetComponent(), transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0,90,90));**

but this only works if the player is in a specific position on the map (look image).

this is the code i have now:

```
 clone = Instantiate(Spear.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(), transform.position, 
 Quaternion.Euler(0,90,90));

 clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * ThrowForce);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should give the rotation in the spear prefab and then just normally spawn it based on the prefab rotation like
Instantiate(Spear, position, Spread.rotation)

or if this doesnt work you can look at this
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html

Comment: I got it all i needed to do was give a 90 rotation to my SpearSpawn Object